# Cleaner way to write JQuery, suggestions for a newbie

Tags: jquery

I'm quite new with JQuery (and javascript) and I've been learning while styling a forum. Recently I came across a section of information that is added automatically from a form (its the output). I can't manipulate the HTML directly and I want to change the style of that output to go with my design. So I decided to use JQuery (and css) to accomplish this.

The code that I wrote works just fine, however I know it's not the cleanest nor the more efficient way. I thought maybe you could give me some feedback on the JQuery code. For example, the part where I delete the Label_1 and Label_6 tags: would be set in just one loop using a for or each? or, since its a code that will be in all the pages of the site, does it matter if I wrap all the code in just one function or its ok just like that?

Thanks in advance!

So what I have initially is this:

```
<div class="info">

<div class="original"><span class="label"><span style="color:#D0C6C4;">Label_1</span> : </span>Value_1<span class="label"><span style="color:#D0C6C4;">Label_2</span> : </span>Value_2<span class="label"><span style="color:#536482;">Label_3</span> : </span>Value_3<span class="label"><span style="color:#536482;">Label_4</span> : </span>Value_4<span class="label"><span style="color:#536482;">Label_5</span> : </span>Value_5<span class="label"><span style="color:#536482;">Label_6</span> : </span>Value_6</div>

<p></p>
</div>
<div class="moreinfo"></div>
```

All the Values (value_1, value_2, …) may change, while the Labels (Label_1, Label_2, …) are known and always the same. The order, in theory, may not change, but I'm not sure. What doesn't will change are the pairs Label_1 followed by Value_1, Label_2 by Value_2, etc.

What I wanted to achieve is this:

```
<div class="info">
  <div class="pair">
    <strong>Label_2</strong><span>Value_2</span>
    <strong>Label_3</strong><span>Value_3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="pair">
    <strong>Label_4</strong><span>Value_4</span>
    <strong>Label_5</strong><span>Value_5</span>
  </div>
                    
  <p>Value_1</p>
</div>

<div class="moreinfo">Value_6</div>
```

What I achieved:

```
<div class="info">
  <div class="pair">
    <span class="span-0">Label_2</span><span class="value span-1">Value_2</span>
    <span class="span-2">Label_3</span><span class="value span-3">Value_3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="pair">
    <span class="span-0">Label_4</span><span class="value span-1">Value_4</span>
    <span class="span-2">Label_5</span><span class="value span-3">Value_5</span>
  </div>
                    
  <p>Value_1</p>
</div>

<div class="moreinfo">Value_6</div>
```

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 //First I deleted de attributes and the ":"
 $('.original span').each(function() {
   $(this).removeAttr('style');
   $(this).removeClass();
   
   var label = $(this).text();
   label = label.replace(' : ','');
   $(this).html(label);
 });
 
 //Wrap the text that is alone (without tags) inside .original
 $('.original').contents().filter(function(){return this.nodeType !=1}).wrap('<span class="value"></span>');
  
 //Deleted Label_1 and Label_6 and positioned in the place I want
 $('.original span').each(function() {
  label = $(this).text();
  if(label == 'Label_1'){
     var label1 = $(this).next().text();
     $('.info p').append(label1);
     $(this).next().remove();
     $(this).remove();
   };
  if(label == 'Label_6'){
    var label6 = $(this).next().text();
    $('.moreinfo').append(label6);
    $(this).next().remove();
    $(this).remove();
  }
});

//Wrap in pairs
var set = $('.original').children();
for(var i=0, len = set.length; i < len; i+=4){
  set.slice(i, i+4).wrapAll('<div class="pair"></div>');};

//Add extra class for each <span> so I can later style the grid-area in CSS
$('.pair').each(function() {
  $(this).children().addClass(function(index){return 'span-' + index});
});

//"Deleted" the .original div
$('.info > .original').contents().unwrap();
});
```

The CSS:

```
.info {
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.info .pair {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "a b" "c d";
    column-gap: 10px;
    row-gap: 5px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.pair span.span-0 {grid-area: a;}
.pair span.span-2 {grid-area: b;}
.pair span.span-1 {grid-area: c;}
.pair span.span-3 {grid-area: d;}

.info span.value {
    background-color: #111;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.pair span.span-0, .pair span.span-2 {
    color: salmon;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Please state what you want to do first properly. Also there is no use of original class in HTML. And also just looking into the code, it is not a clean. I can find two same each function usage. `$('.original span').each(function() {})`

Comment: @PrajwalBati The code that is after the "What I have initially" is where the  `.original` is added. I didn't set that. I can't manipulate the HTML directly, that is why I'm using JQuery. The class has css properties that are not important to the main issue (like font, colors and padding), that is why It seems useless. As for what I want to do, is to go from that initial code to the one after "What I want to achieve", which is the style that I want the output of the form to look like. So far I got the "What I achieved", but in a very rusty way.

Comment: @PrajwalBati And about the same function written twice, I did it because I thought that I needed to wrap the Values in "span" to make the second function works. I thought in giving first that text a class or a tag so then I may be able to call/use it. Do you have any suggestion to avoid that double thing?  I hope I explained myself better now!

Comment: Please consider posting your question to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @user2314737 The question in it's current form is off-topic on Code Review.

Comment: A cleaner way? ... don't use jquery. The lastest JavaScript advances have pretty much made jquery obsolete. See [this info](https://github.com/camsong/You-Dont-Need-jQuery), where there are various examples of the jquery way and equivalent plain JavaScript usage.